# Query top row and others row with equivalent sum value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table like this.

```
A   Sum
5    40
9    40
3    40
4    30
6    20
```

I want to get the top 1 row based on Sum column - in this case it is `5,40` but Sum 40 is in other rows as well, So I want all other rows which have the maximum sum. So, the query should return `5,40 | 9,40 | 3,40`

Answer (score 2):

Just like Mysql, Postgresql query will be simply:

```
select * from your_table where sum = (select sum from your_table order by sum desc limit 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) `dense_rank()` for that:

```
select a, sum
from (
  select a,sum, dense_rank() over (order by sum desc) as rnk
  from the_table
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres 13 now supports `fetch first with ties`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by sum desc
fetch first 1 row with ties;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=53ff52a0ac5b3abcb22341463e0c5c5b) is a db<>fiddle.